# Stripe RedirectToCheckout

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am trying to create some kind of payment modal, where the user clicks on the payment method, in this case Stripe and, in a new tab, it opens the checkout page of stripe.

The problem is that apparently I can't generate the stripe checkout url from server-side, I've to use it in my own function:

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: data.id});
```

I wonder if there's a way in Jquery where I can store the url generated by that function and prevent the redirect, so I can use my own function?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently a way to generate the Checkout URL server side, or otherwise store it.

Just don't call that function until you're ready to actually redirect them.

Comment: Hi @floatingLomas, my goal is to open the redirect in a new tab... any ideas on that?

Comment: That's not possible with Stripe.js Checkout. If you wish to control your own redirect, consider looking at PaymentIntent API 's next_action and Stripe.js confirmCardPayment.

Comment: @floatingLomas Can you please take a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66983230/9409877

Answer (score 1):

my way

1. Use a button 'a link' target=_blank to the stripe button page
2. stripe button page Let it automatically jump to the stripe paypage

```
    $( "#checkout-button" ).on( "click", function() {
       fetch()
    });
    $( "#checkout-button" ).click();
```

3. Or just do it like this

```
    $(function(){
       fetch()
    });
```